# How can I create split screen with boostrap and add responsive image

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Hey guys I am trying to create a 50:50 ration on my split screen layout.Text on one side and picture on the other I was able to get this far.

```
<div class="content-section-a">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-5 col-sm-6">
                <div class="clearfix"></div>
                <h2 class="section-heading">Trying some code:<br>Special Thanks</h2>
                <p class="lead">A special thanks to the community of coders</a> for providing the help and support</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-5 col-lg-offset-2 col-sm-6">
                <img class="img" src="assets/img/prg.jpg">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
.img {
    width: auto;
    height: 250px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using Bootstrap's grid system. Here's some example HTML you could use:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <h2 class="section-heading">Trying some code:<br>Special Thanks</h2>
    <p class="lead">A special thanks to the community of coders</a> for providing the help and support</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">put your images in this section<img class="img" src="assets/img/prg.jpg"></div>
</div>
```

This will put the text section on the left side of the page and the responsive image on the right. If the page is collapsed so it can't fit both horizontally they will stack. You can change this if you like. For more information see Bootstrap's guide on the Grid System. http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

Comment: fantastic. works like a charm. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

What you should use is `col-xs-6` instead of `col-sm-6` because `col-sm-x` is used for screens with min-width: 768px or higher.

You may be seeing it showing at the bottom because your using `sm` instead of `xs` and the screen resolution is below 768px.